# Upgrading from Windows XP to Windows 8

Tags: windows-xp, windows-8

I have four to five computers with an OEM pack with same licence key. All these computers have activated Windows installed on them.

1. Do I need only one licence key for upgrading all these computers to Windows 8?
2. If during installation I get the error message `0xc0000260` (i.e. hardware incompatible), can I use the upgrade key purchased with this computer on some other computer?

Answer (score 3):

1. you must buy 5 keys
2. 0xc0000260 means the CPU is not supported. Make sure the CPU supports PAE, SSE2 and NX-Bit (make sure the NX Bit is enabled in the BIOS).